# How to get the name of mapping data flow inside the mapping data flow?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to get the names of running Mapping data flow in order to track the error details when any pipeline or Data flow fails just same like we track for running pipelines in Azure Data Factory ?

How we can achive this ?

Comment: Hi@SHIVAM YADAV, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

1. We can declare a variable `FlowName`, type in the data flow name, here is `myDataflow`.
   [image]
2. Inside the data flow, we can declare a parameter named `parameter1` and temporarily assign double quotes.
   [image]
3. Then outside the data flow, we can see `paramter1` , select `Pipeline expression`, add dynamic content `@variables('FlowName')`.
   [image]
4. Inside the data flow, `paratmer1` will be assigned the value `myDataflow` at runtime. So we can use `DerivedColumn1` activity to generate a new column with the value `myDataflow`.
   [image]
5. There may be problems with the data preview, but the debugging result is correct. Because this column will assigned at runtime.
   [image]

The data preview is as follows, the column is null value:
[image]

Comment: Hi @SHIVAM YADAV, please correct me if I unstand you wrong in the answer.